# Video editing: Proper length of VOB movie not identified

Tags: video, editing, dvd, time

I copied a VOB from a camcorder disc.  The content is about an hour long, but in Premiere, GOM Media Player or VLC only recognizes the clip is 12 or 3 seconds long.   I tried renaming the file to MPG from VOB with no luck.    Is there anything that can fix this solution?

**Update:** Thanks for the suggestions.   The VOB files in question are the specific videos I'm looking for.  The files are complete copies (same size), and play in all the video players to full length.  They just have a end time of 3 (or 12) seconds, so the playback slider goes to 12, and stops, and the video continues to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, finally something I know about.

In Premiere (CS3) you need to change the file extension to mpg. Just rename the file from .vob to .mpg. Voila, an MPG file.

Then, you may have issues with sound. You need to copy the mpg decoding DLL files from Encore CS3.

ALSO, Emory touched on something important. DVD's have multiple VOB files on them and they are usually all not required except for the actual one used for the video itself. some of them are title files - useless for your purposes.

@Roy, I'm not sure exactly what you want, but basically the MPG format is the format used by DVDs and Hard Drive (HDD - note the second 'D') camcorders today. On DVDs they are called .VOB. MPG is more heavily compressed and that is probably why it is used on HDD camcorders. The format used by tape cameras is AVI, which takes up much more space than MPG (13GB per hour at stabdard definition) but is a much higher quality.

For more info, feel free to comment here or use Google and wikipedia.

Comment: I renamed the files to MPG and they import into CS2 just fine.  Could you put more info about the MPG encoding file down?  Thanks

Comment: Sure, what would you like to know?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying the content over again?  Something may have interrupted the transfer the first time through, preventing you from getting the full video.